# Ad code for Android web app

Tags: android, cordova

I am writing a web app which I plan to release Android app and monetize it with ads.

Most probably I would be using phonegap to convert my web app to android app.

How do I add the advertisement code in my application. In the android tutorial by google, they have shown Java code, how do I get the HTML code for the same?

Comment: FYI: phonegap does not convert to native code, it just wraps your web content with a web view and exposes some native functionality.

Comment: ok i have edited that part of my question

Comment: You don't. Use the java code in your Activity class. It will be displayed over your html webview.